# How to save the images in an MS Access database?

Tags: java, ms-access-2007

I am using MS Access as the database in my project.

Can anyone help me to give idea that how can i save and retrieve images from this database?

Comment: I suspect it's like any other database: connect to it via an [ODBC/JDBC] adapter and and read/write from BLOB fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is generally **NOT** a good idea to save image in database, instead, people usually save the image on disk, and store its path in database.

If you really want to do this, write the images' bytes into a Blob column.

Comment: Yes you are right, storing & retrieving images can be time consuming. It also load the application. Saving Image on Disk the better option.

Answer (score 1):

You need to capture the Image from your front-end, Java Application. After this make connection with the Access Database and store that ByteArray Data ( Photo ) in to Access Data whose data type should be Object.

Answer (score 0):

Create the table in the access database, give the name to field and select it's type as -'OLE' (*Object Linking and Embedding*, the type for storing obects like image, sound, etc.)
And then try this code.