# SQL for Inserting an Image into an MS Access database using Java

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, jdbc

I am trying to insert an image into an MS Access table using Java.

The Access file is called AdvisorImage.accdb. The table is called Image, and it has 2 columns: ID and Picture. ID is a Long Text type, and Picture is an OLE Object type.

My approach is this:

1. I establish a database connection
2. Convert the image to a byte array
3. Create the SQL statement to save the byte array to the database
4. Execute the SQL statement
5. Close connection

Here is the code that I've written so far:

```
package com.database.access;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class dbAccess {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            String database = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.accdb)};DBQ=C://Users/abcde/Documents/AdvisorImage.accdb;";
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(database, "", "");
            Statement s = conn.createStatement();

           //convert file to byte array
           File file = new File("C://Users/abcde/Pictures/WW.PNG");

           FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

           ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
           byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

           try {
                for(int readNum;(readNum = fis.read(buf)) != -1;) {
                    bos.write(buf,0,readNum);
                    System.out.println("read" + readNum + " bytes," );
                }
           } catch (IOException ex) {
               System.out.println(ex);
           }
           byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();

           //write to database
           String addRow = "INSERT INTO " + "Image(ID,Picture) VALUES ( " + String.valueOf((int) (Math.random() * 32767)) + ", ";
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

How would you frame that SQL statement (the String addRow) to specify and insert my byte array, called bytes, into the OLE column of the Image table?

And then my add on question would be, how would you write the SQL and corresponding Java code to retrieve the byte array(s) from the table?

Note: I know that it is not recommended to store images in a database, but my specific situation requires it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to save the images in an MS Access database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046606/how-to-save-the-images-in-an-ms-access-database)

Comment: I saw that post, in fact it was one of the first ones I looked at. That gave me the approach to the problem, but didn't actually provide any code as an example

Answer (score 0):

Using database to store a photo is not preferred due to the high size these photos take (ten times the original size). However, this is the code

```
String addRow = "INSERT INTO " + "Image(ID,Picture) VALUES ( " + String.valueOf((int) (Math.random() * 32767)) +","+ bytes;
```

If it doesn't go well try quoting `bytes` with ' ', [ ] or "  ".